# Laravel 4 - load custom classes

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel, and I'm trying to autoload an entire directory of my own classes. The name of my directory is "templates" so, based on [this post](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=4951) in the Laravel forum, I have added my "templates" directory to app/start/global.php like this:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/templates',

));
```

I then ran `composer dump-autoload` successfully, but my classes still aren't found. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the `directory` in `composer.json` file (in `autoload->classmap`):

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/controllers/admin",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/templates" // <--------
    ]
},
```

Then run (From your project's root folder on `terminal/command prompt`):

```
composer dump-autoload
```